# IO bound threads in ruby

Tags: ruby, concurrency, worker

In a ruby application I have a bunch of tasks which share no state and I want to launch them off many at a time. Crucially, I don't care about the order they are started in, nor their return values (as they will each incur database transactions before they complete). I'm aware that depending on my ruby implementation the GIL may prevent these tasks from actually running at the same time, but that's OK because I'm not actually interested in true concurrency: these worker threads will be IO bound over network requests anyways.

What I've got so far is [this](https://gist.github.com/maxdeliso/5938181):

```
def asyncDispatcher(numConcurrent, stateQueue, &workerBlock)
  workerThreads = []

  while not stateQueue.empty?
    while workerThreads.length < numConcurrent
      nextState = stateQueue.pop

      nextWorker =
        Thread.new(nextState) do |st|
          workerBlock.call(st)
        end

      workerThreads.push(nextWorker)
    end # inner while

    workerThreads.delete_if{|th| not th.alive?} # clean up dead threads
  end # outer while

  workerThreads.each{|th| th.join} # join any remaining workers
end # asyncDispatcher
```

And I invoke it like this:

```
asyncDispatcher(2, (1..10).to_a ) {|x| x + 1}
```

Are there any lurking bugs or concurrency pitfalls here? Or perhaps something in the runtime which would simplify this task?

Comment: Take a look at celluloid.io. It seems like your main loop does a lot of busy waiting too.

Comment: ++ on the busy waiting. This loop: `while workerThreads.length < numConcurrent` could spin millions of times doing nothing while the allowed number of workers are all busy

Comment: before I had the dispatcher thread sleeping and the worker threads waking it up once they completed but this approach had many a corner case and required some locks, which was more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Queue:

```
require 'thread'

def asyncDispatcher(numWorkers, stateArray, &processor)
  q = Queue.new
  threads = []

  (1..numWorkers).each do |worker_id|
    threads << Thread.new(processor, worker_id) do |processor, worker_id|
      while true
        next_state = q.shift      #shift() blocks if q is empty, which is the case now
        break if next_state == q  #Some sentinel that won't appear in your data
        processor.call(next_state, worker_id)
      end
    end
  end

  stateArray.each {|state| q.push state}
  stateArray.each {q.push q}     #Some sentinel that won't appear in your data

  threads.each(&:join)
end


asyncDispatcher(2, (1..10).to_a) do |state, worker_id|
  time = sleep(Random.rand 10)  #How long it took to process state
  puts "#{state} is finished being processed: worker ##{worker_id} took #{time} secs."
end

--output:--
2 is finished being processed: worker #1 took 4 secs.
3 is finished being processed: worker #1 took 1 secs.
1 is finished being processed: worker #2 took 7 secs.
5 is finished being processed: worker #2 took 1 secs.
6 is finished being processed: worker #2 took 4 secs.
7 is finished being processed: worker #2 took 1 secs.
4 is finished being processed: worker #1 took 8 secs.
8 is finished being processed: worker #2 took 1 secs.
10 is finished being processed: worker #2 took 3 secs.
9 is finished being processed: worker #1 took 9 secs.
```

Okay, okay, someone is going look at that output and cry out,

> Hey, #2 took a total of 13 seconds to do four jobs in a row, while #1
>   took only 8 secs. for a job, so #1's output for the 8 sec. job should
>   have come earlier. There's no thread switching in Ruby! Ruby is
>   broken!".

Well, while #1 was sleeping for its first two jobs for a total of 5 seconds, #2 was sleeping at the same time, so #2 only had 2 more seconds left to sleep when #1 finished it's first two jobs. So replace #2's 7 secs by 2 secs, and you'll see that after number #1 finished its first two jobs, #2 took a total of 8 seconds for its run of four jobs in a row, which tied #1 for it's 8 second job.

Comment: instead of using a sentinel could you just break if the queue was empty?

Comment: never mind i see now: you need some way to differentiate between: 'there's more work to do so wait' and 'all the work is done so quit'